# Install SQL Server 2012 to Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2012 in Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Operating System. However this Error keep appearing even though I installed both .NET Framework 3.5.1 and 4.0

> **The operating system on this computer does not meet the minimum requirements for SQL SERVER 2012. For Windows Vista or Windows Server 2008 Operating System. Service Pack 2 or later is required. For windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2, Service Pack 1 or later is required. For more information, see hardware and Software Requirements for installing SQL Server 2012 at**

Comment: Did you verify sp1 was fully patched?

Comment: I do not know, what I only know is I'm using Windows Server 2008 Standard Edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However this Error keep appearing even though I installed both .NET Framework 
>   3.5.1 and 4.0

And why do you think that the .NET framework version would fix that when the error CLEARLY says:

> For windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2, Service Pack 1 or later is required.

THe solution is simple. IGNORE the error - it really is more a warning. And then once you installed SQL Server 2012, immediately patch it.

Comment: Sorry for late reply but yea I updatd my Windows Server 2008 to become SP 1 and it solves the problem I fix this after I commented to Jim. I just realized that I need to update my OS.